# BDD SpecFlow The name ConfigurationManager does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I am trying out BDD using SpecFlow 2.1.0 in Visual Studio 2015
I want to use the App.config file to specify which browser I want to use e.g. Chrome browser and the URL.
To use this i should use the follwing line of code:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["browser"];
```

But I am getting the error:

```
The name ConfigurationManager does not exist in the current context
```

My Step where i have mentioned ConfigurationManager is as follows:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist;

namespace SpecflowFirst.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    class GoogleSearchSteps
    {
        private static IWebDriver _driver;  

        [Given(@"I have navigated to Google page")]
        public void GivenIHaveNavigatedToGooglePage()
        {
            string driverConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["browser"];
            _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"E:\Selenium\Browser Drivers\");
            ConfigureDriver();
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseURL"];)

        }
// etc more steps below
```

My App.config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
  <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config --><unitTestProvider name="NUnit" />
</specFlow>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="baseURL" value="http://www.google.co.uk"/>
    <add key="browser" value="Chrome"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Am I missing a reference package or is my syntax wrong?

Thanks for help, Riaz

Comment: Try specifying System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That does not work

Comment: Hope you have assembly reference to System.Configuration

Comment: That's what I was starting to look at.  I think it is not in the references section when I look at references from Solution explorer

Comment: The assembly reference is not there.  I should use NuGet and install it?

Comment: You should manually add it. Right click Refernces -> Add Reference -> Assemblies. You dont need nuget as it is a .net framework assembly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128568/discussion-between-vinoth-and-riaz-ladhani).

Comment: Got it working now.  Thank you.